# Extract StructType from JSON schema definition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, schema, spark-structured-streaming

I have a schema definition generated by Hackolade. It looks like this:

> ```
> {
> "properties": {
>     "data": {
>         "isActivated": true,
>         "type": "object",
>         "properties": {
>             "value01": {
>                 "isActivated": true,
>                 "type": "string",
>                 "readOnly": true,
>                 "description": "description 01",
>                 "pattern": "^([a-z _-]*)$",
>                 "minLength": 4,
>                 "examples": [
>                     "example01",
>                     "example02"
>                 ],
>                 "$comment": "comment 01."
>             },
>             "start_timestamp": {
>                 "isActivated": true,
>                 "type": "string",
>                 "format": "date-time",
>                 "pattern": "^(\\d{4}(?!\\d{2}\\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\\3([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\\d|[12]\\d{2}|3([0-5]\\d|6[1-6])))([T\\s]((([01]\\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\\d)?|24\\:?00)([\\.,]\\d+(?!:))?)?(\\17[0-5]\\d?)?([zZ]|([\\+-])([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)?)?)?)?(.\\d{6})?(\\+00:00)$",
>                 "readOnly": true,
>                 "examples": [
>                     "2022-08-15T12:50:25.456789+00:00"
>                 ],
>                 "description": "timestamp description",
>                 "maxLength": 33,
>                 "minLength": 27
>             }
>         },
>         "additionalProperties": false,
>         "description": "data description",
>         "readOnly": true,
>         "required": [
>             "value01",
>             "start_timestamp"
>         ]
>     }
> } }
> ```

I want to convert this schema definition to a StructType schema to use with PySpark DF:

```
df_with_json = df.withColumn("col_with_schema", f.from_json(f.col(value), schema))
```

Where value column is a dict string:

```
'{"data":{"value01":"example01", "start_timestamp":"2021-05-12T12:42:56.236123+00:00"}}'
```

I tried something like: `schema = f.schema_of_json(f.lit(str(json_schema_definition)))` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following will convert your JSON string into a StructType object. The issue is that you have regexes as values in your JSON, so before conversion you must do a small `replace`.

```py
json_str = """
{
"properties": {
    "data": {
        "isActivated": true,
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "value01": {
                "isActivated": true,
                "type": "string",
                "readOnly": true,
                "description": "description 01",
                "pattern": "^([a-z _-]*)$",
                "minLength": 4,
                "examples": [
                    "example01",
                    "example02"
                ],
                "$comment": "comment 01."
            },
            "start_timestamp": {
                "isActivated": true,
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time",
                "pattern": "^(\\d{4}(?!\\d{2}\\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\\3([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\\d|[12]\\d{2}|3([0-5]\\d|6[1-6])))([T\\s]((([01]\\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\\d)?|24\\:?00)([\\.,]\\d+(?!:))?)?(\\17[0-5]\\d?)?([zZ]|([\\+-])([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)?)?)?)?(.\\d{6})?(\\+00:00)$",
                "readOnly": true,
                "examples": [
                    "2022-08-15T12:50:25.456789+00:00"
                ],
                "description": "timestamp description",
                "maxLength": 33,
                "minLength": 27
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "description": "data description",
        "readOnly": true,
        "required": [
            "value01",
            "start_timestamp"
        ]
    }
} }
"""

schema = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json_str.replace('\\', '\\\\\\\\')])).schema

print(schema)
# StructType([StructField('properties', StructType([StructField('data', StructType([StructField('additionalProperties', BooleanType(), True), StructField('description', StringType(), True), StructField('isActivated', BooleanType(), True), StructField('properties', StructType([StructField('start_timestamp', StructType([StructField('description', StringType(), True), StructField('examples', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True), StructField('format', StringType(), True), StructField('isActivated', BooleanType(), True), StructField('maxLength', LongType(), True), StructField('minLength', LongType(), True), StructField('pattern', StringType(), True), StructField('readOnly', BooleanType(), True), StructField('type', StringType(), True)]), True), StructField('value01', StructType([StructField('$comment', StringType(), True), StructField('description', StringType(), True), StructField('examples', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True), StructField('isActivated', BooleanType(), True), StructField('minLength', LongType(), True), StructField('pattern', StringType(), True), StructField('readOnly', BooleanType(), True), StructField('type', StringType(), True)]), True)]), True), StructField('readOnly', BooleanType(), True), StructField('required', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True), StructField('type', StringType(), True)]), True)]), True)])
```